# RDD to multidimensional array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark's python API and I am finding a few matrix operations challenging. My RDD is one dimensional list of length n (row vector). Is it possible to reshape it to a matrix/multidimensional array of size sq_root(n) x Sq_root(n).

for example,

```
Vec=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and desired output 3 x 3=

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]]
```

Is there an equivalent to reshape in numpy?

Conditions: 
n (>50 million) is huge so that rules out using .collect(),
and can this process be made to run on multiple threads?

Comment: Did you consider a distributed matrix?

Comment: am I incorrect in thinking that Distributed matrix are implemented only in Scale and Java and not python API?

Comment: @KentCarlevi You're right, there are no distributed data structures in PySpark yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should to the trick:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, 10))
nrow = int(rdd.count() ** 0.5) # Compute number of rows

rows = (rdd.
   zipWithIndex(). # Add index, we assume that data is sorted
   groupBy(lambda (x, i): i / nrow). # Group by row
   # Order by column and drop index
   mapValues(lambda vals: [x for (x, i) in sorted(vals, key=lambda (x, i): i)])))
```

You can add:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
rows.mapValues(DenseVector)
```

if you want proper vectors.