# pyspark spark RDD to 3D matrix

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using pyspark to perform matrix operations. I have been trying to convert a spark dataframe to 3D matrix.
My dataframe looks like this(x_input):

```
Prod  | Location  |    Day |    Sales  
---------------------------------
0       0           0          65.4
1       0           0          96.1
2       0           0          98.1
3       0           0          9.5
0       0           1          16.1
1       0           1          59.4
2       0           1          17
3       0           1          92.8
0       1           0          52.3
1       1           0          41.1
2       1           0          14.6
3       1           0          92.2
0       1           1          27.7
1       1           1          69
2       1           1          50.7
3       1           1          53.4
0       2           0          54
1       2           0          50.4
2       2           0          54.6
3       2           0          1.3
0       2           1          2.7
1       2           1          60.6
2       2           1          77.7
3       2           1          21.7
```

Prod, Location and Day columns are the indices of matrix where I want to put the Sales value and the output should be like:

```
[
[
  [65.4, 96.1, 98.1, 9.5],
  [16.1, 59.4, 17, 92.8]
],
[
  [52.3, 41.1, 14.6, 92.2],
  [27.7, 69, 50.7, 53.4]
],
[
  [54, 50.4, 54.6, 1.3],
  [2.7, 60.6, 77.7, 21.7]
]
]
```

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597151/rdd-to-multidimensional-array) and came up with this solution :

```
x_rdd = x_input.rdd

rows = (x_rdd
       .zipWithIndex()
       .groupBy(lambda (x,i): i/4)
       .mapValues(lambda vals: [x.Sales for (x,i) in sorted(vals, key=lambda (x, i): i)]))

f = rows.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

after doing so, f is now a 2D matrix, how can I convert it to 3D matrix as mentioned above?

A for loop approach is not possible as the 3D matrix will have large dimensions.